Malliavin calculus for the regularity of the density of the supremum of a process
I am reading Chapter 2 from Nualart's book 'The Malliavin calculus and related topics'.
Proposition 2.1.10 gives the conditions for the law of the supremum of a process to have a density. Condition (ii) requires ${DX(t), t \in S}$ to possess a continuous version.
I want to apply this Proposition for a solution to an SPDE $u(t,x)$, in order to show that the law of the supremum of $u(t,x)$ has a density.
I am stuck at the part of showing that $Du$ possesses a continous version. I am thinking of applying the Kolmogorov criterion, but I am confused about what I would need to show exactly.It seems to me that I would need to show the following for the Malliavin derivative $D_{s,y}u(t,x)$:
$$
E[ |D_{s,y} u(t,x)- D_{s,y} u(t',x')|^{p}] \leq C \left( |t-t'|^{\alpha}+|x-x'|^{\beta} \right)
$$
for some exponents $p,\alpha,\beta$.
I am not sure if this is correct. Does $(s,y)$ need to vary as well? Would I need to show this instead:
$$
E[ |D_{s,y} u(t,x)- D_{s',y'} u(t,x)|^{p}] \leq C \left( |s-s'|^{\alpha}+|y-y'|^{\beta} \right)
$$
or perhaps this:
$$
E[ |D_{s,y} u(t,x)- D_{s',y'} u(t',x')|^{p}] \leq C \left( |s-s'|^{\alpha}+|y-y'|^{\beta}+|t-t'|^{\gamma}+|x-x'|^{\delta} \right)
$$
for $Du$ to have a continuous version as required by the Proposition?
I am attaching the Proposition and its proof here for reference. Thank you all in advance!


Indeed,
$$
E[ |D_{s,y} u(t,x)- D_{s',y'} u(t',x')|^{p}] \leq C \left( |s-s'|^{\alpha}+|y-y'|^{\beta}+|t-t'|^{\gamma}+|x-x'|^{\delta} \right)
$$
is one way to show existence of a continuous modification using the Kolmogorov continuity theorem. There are weaker conditions that still give continuity e.g. Dudley's continuity theorem using the metric entropy (eg. here and here for more references).
In the article "Distribution of the integral of maximum processes and applications", they show some similar results for the Malliavin derivative but only assume continuity partly: for each fixed $r$ the stochastic process $(D_rX_t)_{t\in[0,T]}$ possesses a continuous version.

Thank you for your reply Thomas! I am still confused, as it seems to me that I have to show that for each fixed $t$ the stochastic process $(D_{s} X_t){s \in [0,T]}$ possesses a continuous version. That is because for any random variable $F$, the Malliavin derivative $D{s} F$ is a stochastic process, according to Nualart's book,  I thought that's what he means in this Proposition too. However, it is not clear how this is used in the Proposition proof. Could you elaborate on which of the two versions would be correct and why? ( the full version modifying both $t,s,x,y$ is too hard to show).

@user574579 Other way around. Please read the article I included. For prop 2.1.10 to go through, you have to show that for each fixed $r$, the process $$G_{t}:=D_{r}X_{t}$$ is continuous in $t$. So you are free to fix r and show that
$$
E[ |D_{r} X_{t}- D_{r} X_{s}|^{p}] \leq C \left( |t-s|^{\alpha} \right).
$$
